# Getting two open session when working with thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, autowired

I'm working with thread to stored some data in parallel in the database with hibernate. I need to do that because before saving the information to the database I need to run some task that takes several minutes. So I implemented threads.

So, I have to instance of the same class, let say Students, so each student has a unique Code (not the ID) that I generate randomly and in order to make sure that it is unique, before saving that student I check that there is not other student with that code.

The issue is that when I want to check for the second student if the code is unique (the first one was stored correctly) I get

```
HibernateException: illegally attempted to associate a proxy with two open Sessions
```

when I'm doing the select...
I'm using Autowired class to instaciate the other classes (Services, Dao, etc) and Runnable for the Thread.

Below you have some code:
StudentServiceImpl:

```
@Autowired
RunSomeTaskService runSomeTaskService;
@Override
Transactional
public Response save(StudentBO[] students, String username) throws Exception {
...
for (StudentBO student : students) {
    Student s = new Student();
    String code = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    while(this.studentDao.getByCode(code) != null)
        code = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    s.setCode(code);
    ....
    this.studentDao.save(s);
    runSomeTaskService.setData(s);
    Thread t = new Thread(runSomeTaskService);
    t.start();
}
```

RunSomeTaskService:

```
public interface RunSomeTaskService extends Runnable{
    void setData(Student student);
    Response getResponse();
}
```

RunSomeTaskServiceImpl:

```
public class RunSomeTaskServiceImpl extends CommonService implements RunSomeTaskService{

Response response;
Student student;
@Override
    public void setData(Student student) {
          this.response = new Response();
          this.student = student;
       }
}

@Override
    public Response getResponse() {
        return this.response;
    }

@Override
    @Transactional
    public void run() {
//do some process that takes minutes
this.studentDao.add(this.student);
this.response = response;
}
```

StudentDaoImpl:

```
@Override
    public Object addOrUpdate(Object item) throws Exception {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(item);
        return item;
    }

@Override
    public Object getByCode(String code) throws Exception {
        Query q = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("FROM Student as e WHERE e.code = '" + code + "'");
        return q.uniqueResult();
    }
```

So my questions are:

1 - Is it ok to instantiate RunSomeTaskService with Autowired? I need this becase if I use `new RunSomeTaskService()`, sessionFactory is null in the dao layer. But maybe in this way is it wrong because I use just one instance for all the students

2 - In order to avoid `the proxy with two open Sessions` error, I cannot consult the student table inside the `for (StudentBO student : students)`. Is that ok or is the issue is different?

BTW it's my first time working with thread.

Comment: DO NOT set data state to your RunSomeTaskServiceImpl because the default config by spring lets the object as a Singleton. I would recommend to use @Async in your service

Comment: @WilderValera With Async can I define that for same cases I need to wait for a response but for others I do not want to wait for the response?

Comment: You can use @Async de return a Future<T>, then, depending on your case, you can use the get method(this will block the thread) to return the value. Take a look to this post http://www.baeldung.com/spring-async

Comment: @WilderValera I implemented Async, but it is not working. It will be great if you can help me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51680156/async-not-working-in-spring-api-rest-with-interfaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make it work!

I was saving the student object inside the foreach and then starting a new Thread with that object.

The solution was to first run a foreach to stored all the students, and then another foreach to start the different Threads sending the object already stored.