# @Async not working in Spring API rest with Interfaces

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm working with @Async to stored some data in parallel in the database with hibernate. I need to do that because before saving the information to the database I need to run some task that takes several minutes. So I implemented @Async.

The issue is that @Async seems to not be working. Please find the code below:

WebConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

}
```

StudentServiceImpl:

```
@Autowired
RunSomeTaskService runSomeTaskService;

@Override
Transactional
public Response saveWithoutWaiting(StudentBO[] students, String username) throws Exception {
...
for (StudentBO student : students) {
    ....
    Future<Response> response = runSomeTaskService.doTasks(student);
    //Finish without waiting for doTasks().
}

@Override
    Transactional
    public Response saveWithWaiting(StudentBO[] students, String username) throws Exception {
    ...
    for (StudentBO student : students) {
        ....
        Future<Response> response = runSomeTaskService.doTasks(student);
        //Finish and wait for doTasks().
        response.get();
    }
```

RunSomeTaskService:

```
public interface RunSomeTaskService{
    @Async
    public Future<Response> doTasks(Student student);
}
```

RunSomeTaskServiceImpl:

```
public class RunSomeTaskServiceImpl extends CommonService implements RunSomeTaskService{

Student student;
@Override
    public Future<Response> doTasks(Student student) {
          Response response = new Response();
          this.student = student;
          //do Task
          return new AsyncResult<Response>(response);
       }
}
```

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <display-name>Sample Spring Maven Project</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
        </filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>encoding</param-name>
      <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>jwtTokenAuthFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>jwtTokenAuthFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

spring.config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config  />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.app.controller" />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        ...
    </bean>

    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
...
    </bean>


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>//every model generated with Hibernate</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="studentService" class="com.app.services.StudentServiceImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="studentDao" class="com.app.dao.StudentDaoImpl"></bean>
    ...

    <bean id="jwtTokenAuthFilter" class="com.app.security.JWTTokenAuthFilter" />       
</beans>
```

So, could you please help me to understand why @Async is not working?

UPDATE: @Async is now working, but I'm not getting the expected results.

For the case, that I have to wait for the result (sync case)  CompletableFuture.get() is not waiting for the response and I'm getting and error:

My code:

```
CompletableFuture<Response> res = extractDataService.doTask(student);
```

The error:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions. Collection : <unknown>
Collection contents: [[]]
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.setCurrentSession(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:627)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.OnUpdateVisitor.processCollection(OnUpdateVisitor.java:46)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractVisitor.processValue(AbstractVisitor.java:104)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractVisitor.processValue(AbstractVisitor.java:65)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractVisitor.processEntityPropertyValues(AbstractVisitor.java:59)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractVisitor.process(AbstractVisitor.java:126)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:293)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:227)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:92)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:648)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:640)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:635)
        at com.app.dao.CommonDaoImpl.addOrUpdate(CommonDaoImpl.java:28)
        at com.app.services.ExtractDataServiceImpl.doExtraction(ExtractDataServiceImpl.java:361)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1.call(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionAspectSupport$CompletableFutureDelegate$1.get(AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

When I don't have to wait and I execute several cases in Async way I get:

```
12:17:44.040 [DEMO-4] DEBUG o.h.r.t.b.j.i.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl - JDBC transaction marked for rollback-only (exception provided for stack trace)
java.lang.Exception: exception just for purpose of providing stack trace
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.markRollbackOnly(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:265) [hibernate-core-5.0.6.Final.jar:5.0.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:156) [hibernate-core-5.0.6.Final.jar:5.0.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38) [hibernate-core-5.0.6.Final.jar:5.0.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231) [hibernate-core-5.0.6.Final.jar:5.0.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:65) [hibernate-core-5.0.6.Final.jar:5.0.6.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:581) [spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761) [spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730) [spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:485) [spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291) [spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) [spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1.call(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:108) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionAspectSupport$CompletableFutureDelegate$1.get(AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.java:237) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590) [na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
12:17:44.043 [DEMO-4] DEBUG o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager - Initiating transaction rollback after commit exception
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.app.model.FieldValue entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
```

Comment: What is this line `future.get()` ?

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi as far as I understand is to force to wait for the task to be completed... But I'm using it just in the saveWithWaiting mehtod.

Comment: Yes, but `future` is not declared in your code, ignoring the syntax error after.

Comment: Also, it is enough to have `@Async` only for the interface. Btw, how can you tell that it is not working?

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi I fixed the errors in the text (anyway in the app was ok). I removed the Async from the implementation and I still get the same result.
How I know that it is not working, because the process takes some minutes, so my intention is that the API rest generate a response to the user without waiting for that process, but the app wait those minutes and when all the process are done, the API generate the response. Also debugging, It didn't move from doTasks line to the next one until doTasks is complete.

Comment: `@Async` isn't tagged with `@Inherited` it needs to be placed on the method that needs to be async. It also needs to avoid any proxied methods .

Comment: @DarrenForsythe could you please explain? Where should I add Inherited? In the interface or in the implementation? Also, how can I check if the method is proxied or not?

Comment: `get()` is a blocking method, when you call it in a loop it will wait until the current `Future` is completed and moves to the next one.

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi But in saveWithoutWaiting I'm not calling get() and it block it anyway

Comment: I made a mistake for the `@Async`, as Darren Forsythe said, it has to be on the implementation, not on the interface. I don't see anything other wrong with your code.

Comment: MM but it keeps without working... maybe something in the spring-config.xml ?

Comment: in saveWithoutWaiting how do you deal with future responses?

Comment: @Rohit I don’t deal with it.. I don’t need to know which is the response, for that reason I’m interested in using something really Async

Comment: Could you please add log with thread name in `doTasks` and `saveWithoutWaiting` method, just to check if they are called in the same thread. And are you sure the `WebConfig ` gets scanned when you start your application?

Comment: Is it possible to share project on github?I suspect there may be problem in code other than the code shared here. @grape_mao is correct, debugging can be misleading in multithreaded app.

Comment: @grape_mao I printed 'Thread.currentThread().getName()' inside the Async function and I everytime I got http-nio-8080-exec-3 as Thread Name. I think that WebConfig is scanned because when I did what Faiz in his answer suggested, I get and error because the context was declared twice.

Comment: @Rohit the code is from a medium/large project.. I cannot share.. for that reason I shared the minify version of the classes... But there I'm doing some image processing and OCR in Command Line and saving the result in MySQL with Hibernate. When I use Thread directly, it works fine (works in ASync way) but I cannot stored objects in the database in parallel.

Comment: @Faabass better add log in `saveWithoutWaiting` as well, otherwise we cannot compare. And the answer provided by Faiz is in conflict with your web.xml, it has nothing to do with `WebConfig`. Do make sure your configuration class is scanned by Spring.

Comment: @grape_mao When I do what Faiz said, I get java.lang.IllegalStateException: No unique WebApplicationContext found: more than one DispatcherServlet registered with publishContext=true?

Comment: @Faabass can you share your spring-config.xml file?

Comment: `@Async` is working perfectly fine actually. The problem is you haven't specified a specific `TaskExecutor` to launch your threads with. Also async request processing (`<async-supported>true</async-supported>`) is something then async executing a method. Those are different beasts. Also your implementation of `RunSomeTaskServiceImpl` is flawed as it isn't thread safe. Another question next to the `DispatcherServlet` do you have a `ContextLoaderListener` which is loading th services? As that would make your `@EnableAsync` pretty much useless as that lives in a different context.

Comment: @Rohit done! could you please take a look at it?

Comment: As far as I know, asynchronous REST API calls can only be implemented with Jersey: https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/async.html. I have implemented these with Spring boot + Jersey.

Comment: @Async should be on the impl , not on the interface , that will solve it, and remember it will only happen when u will call this method using the framwork .

Comment: The latest exception stack looks like transaction boundary and cascade issue. We would need to see the `Student` entity and what you do in the task. I would again ask to create a new question rather than updating this question.

Comment: One quick thing to remember, transactions don't move from thread to thread. If you are taking this async, you need to be careful with your use of Cascade. As @Rohit mentioned, Please present the entity in your post.

Comment: Thanks! I created a new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51831843/hibernate-two-open-sessions-when-working-with-future-and-aync

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More Sophisticated way would be to implement AsyncConfigurer and set the AsyncExecutor to threadPoolTaskExecutor.

Sample Code below

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync(proxyTargetClass=true) //detects @Async annotation
public class AsyncConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {

 public Executor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(10); // create 10 Threads at the time of initialization
        executor.setQueueCapacity(10); // queue capacity
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(25); // if queue is full, then it will create new thread and go till 25
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("DEMO-");
        executor.initialize();//Set up the ExecutorService.
        return executor;
    }

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        return threadPoolTaskExecutor();
    }

    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        return new YOUR_CUSTOM_EXCEPTION_HANDLER();
    }

}
```

The above configuration will detect @Async annotation wherever mentioned

Comment: This was the issue... I created a new class in the same package than WebConfig and added the package in the base-package, but I still keep getting error for the database session... I got that the session is duplicated and things like that...

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the stack trace? Thanks.

Comment: Sure! added.. I getting hopeless about this. What I'm doing is I'm doing some process and then I'm updating those students in the database in parallel way

Comment: This make the app to execute the methos in async way!

Answer (score 5):

Just use:

```
servlet.setAsyncSupported(true);
```

For Example

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(WebConfig.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher",
            new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.setAsyncSupported(true); //Servlets were marked as supporting async
        // For CORS Pre Filght Request
        servlet.setInitParameter("dispatchOptionsRequest", "true");
    }
}
```

Comment: I implemented that in WebConfig.java and I got and error saying that I have two ApplicationContext.. So, then I found that in the web.xml I have to add <async-supported>true</async-supported> for doing the same config that you suggested, but it's also not working... I added the definition of web.xml to the post so you can check

Comment: This is the error I get 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No unique WebApplicationContext found: more than one DispatcherServlet registered with publishContext=true?

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally I make it work...

I used Executors in the following way:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(students.size());
for (StudentBO student : students) {
    executor.submit(() -> extractDataService.doTask(student));
}
```

Where doTask is a regular function, that when I don't need it to work in a different thread, I just call it as it is. When I need the threads, I use the code above.

Comment: This is only a workaround. Of cause using your own executor will do the work.

Comment: With this you do not need `@Async`.

Comment: The code is dangerous as you are creating thread pools without ever cleaning them up. Eventually you will run out of resources and a lot of idle threads. If you want this you have to `shutdown` the `executor` in a `finally` block. Also your want to limit the number of threads and don't want to create 100 threads if you only have 16 cores in your system being able to do the work.

Comment: @M.Deinum and the finally will be fired AFTER all the threads are done? Or how do I make sure they are completed before triggering the finally block?

Comment: The `shutdown` closes as soon as there are no more tasks to process.

Answer (score 0):

There is possibility that the @EnableAsync annotation in WebConfig.java is never scanned. The web.xml points to the spring-context.xml.

You can change the DispatcherServlet definition in web.xml to:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            com.yourpackage.WebConfig
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
```

And include all configuration from spring-config.xml to this class.

**Or** 
Add `<task:annotation-driven>` in spring-config.xml.

**Updated**

Currently, `com.app.controller` package is scanned in spring-config.xml. Make sure the WebConfig.java is in this package or one of it's sub-package. If not add WebConfig's package to base package attribute separated by comma.

Additionally, you can control the thread pool used by async task. Create a executor bean

```
@Bean
public Executor asyncTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(5);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("asynctaskpool-");
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}
```

And in your async method use the bean name like this

```
@Async("asyncTaskExecutor")
public Future<Response> doTasks(Student student);
```

This will ensure all task will be executed in this thread pool.

Comment: I added the spring-config.xml could you please take a look and share your opinion?

Comment: @Faabass Is your WebConfig.java in the package com.app.controller or it's subpackage? If not then it is not scanned and it's package needs to be added to base packages. Base-package attribute can have multiple comma separated packages like `base-package="x.y.z.service, x.y.z.controller"`.

Comment: Thank! I added that to the base-package and now it is working in @Async, anyway I0m having other issues. please see my post

Comment: I would strongly suggest to ask a new question and mark this as answer for the original question.

Comment: done! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51831843/hibernate-two-open-sessions-when-working-with-future-and-aync

Answer (score 0):

You can do CompletableFuture , with this you know when all your tasks are complete

```
List<CompletableFuture<T>> futureList = new ArrayList<>();

for(Student student:studentList){

CompletableFuture<T> returnedFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> doSomething(student),executor).exceptionally(e -> {
        log.error("Error occured in print something future",e);
        return 0;
    });

futureList.add(returnedFuture);
}

Completable.allOf(futureList);
```

Then you can pipeline with thenCompose or thenApply (to take consumer) to have complete control on the task pipeline. you can shutdonw executors when you are done safely.

[CompletetableFuture.allOff javadoc for more info](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf-java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...-)

Comment: I updated the code to use CompletableFuture.. but I'm getting errors with the hibernate session, I added the stracktrace in my post