# Hibernate two open sessions when working with Future and @Aync

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, hibernate

I'm trying to use Multithread in my app to do some tasks that take some minutes to complete.
The idea is that I have n number of objects so I want those to be processed in parallel and without making the user (web app) wait for them to be completed (as it takes several minutes). Also in other case (when the amount of object is one), I want to wait until the process is done so the user can see the result.

But I'm having some issues.

So my code is:
RunSomeTaskServiceImpl:

```
public class RunSomeTaskServiceImpl extends CommonService implements RunSomeTaskService{

    @Async
    @Override
        public Future<Response> doTasks(Student student) {
              Response response = new Response();
              //do Tasks
              return new AsyncResult<Response>(response);
           }
    }
```

RunSomeTaskService:

```
public interface RunSomeTaskService{
    public Future<Response> doTasks(Student student);
}
```

StudentServiceImpl:

```
@Autowired
RunSomeTaskService runSomeTaskService;

@Override
Transactional
public Response save(StudentBO[] students) throws Exception {
    ...
    for (StudentBO student : students) {
        ....
        Future<Response> response = runSomeTaskService.doTasks(student);
        if(students.size() == 1){
           return response.get();
        }
    }
....
}
```

So when there is more than one student, I get the error:

```
12:17:44.040 [DEMO-4] DEBUG o.h.r.t.b.j.i.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl - JDBC transaction marked for rollback-only (exception provided for stack trace)
java.lang.Exception: exception just for purpose of providing stack trace
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.markRollbackOnly(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:265) [hibernate-core-5.0.6.Final.jar:5.0.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:156) [hibernate-core-5.0.6.Final.jar:5.0.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38) [hibernate-core-5.0.6.Final.jar:5.0.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231) [hibernate-core-5.0.6.Final.jar:5.0.6.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:65) [hibernate-core-5.0.6.Final.jar:5.0.6.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:581) [spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761) [spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730) [spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:485) [spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291) [spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) [spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1.call(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:108) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionAspectSupport$CompletableFutureDelegate$1.get(AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.java:237) [spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590) [na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
12:17:44.043 [DEMO-4] DEBUG o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager - Initiating transaction rollback after commit exception
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.app.model.FieldValue entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
```

And when there is just one:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions. Collection : <unknown>
Collection contents: [[]]
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.setCurrentSession(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:627)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.OnUpdateVisitor.processCollection(OnUpdateVisitor.java:46)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractVisitor.processValue(AbstractVisitor.java:104)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractVisitor.processValue(AbstractVisitor.java:65)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractVisitor.processEntityPropertyValues(AbstractVisitor.java:59)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractVisitor.process(AbstractVisitor.java:126)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:293)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:227)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:92)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:648)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:640)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:635)
        at com.app.dao.CommonDaoImpl.addOrUpdate(CommonDaoImpl.java:28)
        at com.app.services.ExtractDataServiceImpl.doExtraction(ExtractDataServiceImpl.java:361)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1.call(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionAspectSupport$CompletableFutureDelegate$1.get(AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Student model

```
package com.app.model;
// Generated 18-jul-2018 15:27:32 by Hibernate Tools 5.2.10.Final

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;

/**
 * Student generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "student", catalog = "school_db", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "code"))
public class Student implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Grade grade;
    private Set<Subject> subjects = new HashSet<Subject>(0);

    public Student() {
    }


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)

    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "grade")
    public Grade getGrade() {
        return this.grade;
    }

    public void setGrade(Grade grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "student")
    public Set<Subject> getSubjects() {
        return this.subjects;
    }

    public void setSubjects(Set<Subject> subjects) {
        this.subjects = subjects;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "student")
    public Set<Subject> getSubjects() {
        return this.subjects;
    }

}
```

spring-config.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config  />
<!--    <context:component-scan base-package="com.app.controller, com.app.security" /> -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.app.controller" />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
....
<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.app.model.Student</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
...
```

So could you please help me to avoid this issues?

Comment: In `RunSomeTaskServiceImpl` why do you need `Student student` as a field?  Would this Thread safe?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. That’s some piece of code from a test, but it’s not impacting the functionality

Comment: *without making the user (web app) wait for them to be completed* I confused as to what you are trying to achieve.  If the simple insertion of objects into you DB is taking a long time, then consider using a batch insert and also consider using a long polling solution

Comment: I’m doing some image processing.. that’s what is taking some minutes.. after the process, I stores some information in the DB

Comment: maybe you should separate out this two steps.  Judging by the error message it seems that the same `Array` of objects is trying to be saved by two (or more) different Threads.

Comment: I save all the objects in the main thread, and then start doing the process of the object in their own thread. I do this, so I can show to the user the list of objects I’m processing

Comment: That `Student student;` instance variable is not thread safe. How do you know it's not causing your problem?

Comment: @Rohit fixed and still getting the same error

Comment: @ScaryWombat what do you mean? I need to save the objects in the main thread so I can show the user what I will be doing, and then I need to process the object in a parallel way

Comment: Can you share the `@Transactional` annoatation with propogation attribute on `ExtractDataServiceImpl` or `ExtractDataServiceImpl.doExtraction()`?

Comment: @Rohit I'm not setting the propagation attribute in any section, I'm just using Transaction, I checked in the config files but there is nothing about that.. I uploaded some section of my spring-config where you can see some definition about transaction in my code